# How to make infinite loop in an Activity

Tags: android

When somebody is doing some game they can do it like this: `mainActivity` which extends `Activity` and in this main activity there is a method e.g:

```
setContentView(BouncingBallView);
```

`BouncingBallView` extends `View` and there we have got methods: `onDraw()` `invalidate()` and these methods are use to do update and they are performing in all frames.

My problem is I would like to have some method like "onDraw-invalidate" which are update but in class `Activity` not in `View`.

I would like to know if there are some main loop, methods which are perform all the time some `update()`? I know that in `Activity` there is: `onCreate()`; `onStart()`; `onRestart()`; `onResume()`; `onPause()`; `onStop()`; and `onDestroy()`, but I can't see update? How would I do this?

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to create a separate ``Thread`` for your "infinite" loop. :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want periodic updates? Then a timer might be a way to go. Create an instance of a timer in your activity's onStart and schedule an update task with a desired delay as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  private Timer timer;
  private BouncingBallView ballView;

  ...

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    timer = new Timer();
    // This timer task will be executed every 1 sec.
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        ballView.update();
      }
    }, 0, 1000);
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void onSuspend() {
    // Suspend the updates when the activity is inactive.
    timer.cancel();
  }
}
```

Note that timer tasks run in a separate thread, and in Android modifying UI elements in a different thread from the one they were created in may cause problems. If you run into these problems handlers (android.os.Handler) are helpful, and in Honeycomb there are better solutions for that but the Timer/Handler combination works well in older versions.